# Finding element in array C

Tags: c

I have an array of 32 characters. I want to find the 2 numbers in my array as in the output, it will write the index of the first 2 found and then add up how many 2s there are until it finds 1. how can I do this? For example:

```
i: 0 val: 1
i: 1 val: 1
i: 2 val: 2
i: 3 val: 2
i: 4 val: 2
i: 5 val: 2
i: 6 val: 2
i: 7 val: 1
i: 8 val: 1
i: 9 val: 1
i: 10 val: 2
i: 11 val: 2
i: 12 val: 2
i: 13 val: 2
i: 14 val: 2
i: 15 val: 1
i: 16 val: 1
i: 17 val: 1
i: 18 val: 1
i: 19 val: 1
i: 20 val: 1
i: 21 val: 1
i: 22 val: 1
i: 23 val: 1
i: 24 val: 1
i: 25 val: 1
i: 26 val: 1
i: 27 val: 1
i: 28 val: 1
i: 29 val: 2
i: 30 val: 2
i: 31 val: 2
```

The output I want is:

```
2 5 
10 5
29 3
```

Comment: `puts("2 5\n10 5\n29 3")`. If you want a more serious answer, you'll need to provide a better description of the problem.

Comment: ie, are you looking for runs of `2`, or are you looking for runs of values that are not 1, or are you looking for the length of any run that differs from the first entry, or ....?  There are many reasonable problem descriptions that will produce the output you show.

Comment: I tried to explain in more detail, can you take a look again?

Comment: @Sandy Dikenssen Does the character  array contain characters like '1' and '2' or like integers 1 and 2?

Comment: actually it holds integer but @WilliamPursell s answer is enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        char a[] = {
                1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
                1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
        };
        int count = 0;
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof *a + 1; i++ ){
                if( i < sizeof a / sizeof *a && a[i] == 2 ){
                        if( count++ == 0 ){
                                printf("%d", i);
                        }
                } else {
                        if( count ){
                                printf(" %d\n", count);
                        }
                        count = 0;
                }

        }
}
```